# Android: is it possible to open a Chrome Custom Tab in the background or partially hidden?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I'd like to open a Chrome Custom Tab either partially hidden (i.e. visible to the user but not blocking main content) or fully hidden in the background. Is this possible with the Android SDK?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The Chrome Custom Tab always loads in the foreground and full-screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with Partial Custom Tabs if the browser supports it:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/integration-guide/#specify-the-launch-height-of-a-custom-tab